# Python, Pivot for recommender model

Tags: python, pivot, collaborative-filtering, recommendation-engine

I have a rating dataset having userid, restaurantid, and ratings ( by the user for a particular restaurant; the rating can 0,1,2).
When I am doing pivoting to create a user-item matrix, I am replacing the nan (when the user has not rated a restaurant) values with zero.
My question is am I assigning a zero rating here? Am I saying that user1 has rated res1 as zero when he has not rated res1 at all? Isn't it going to affect my final prediction?

Comment: Yes it will affect your results definitely, even common indicators like average rating, etc/ You metter remove nans completely

Comment: Can you add a schematic diagram or an illustration pic for some "weak" brained peoples and laymen's all over the world like me?.